# GetPort method in JAX WSimplementation

Tags: jax-ws

In the web service tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)

What is the

```
> Hello port = service.getHelloPort();
```

doing? I mean in my experience the getPort() method is implemented in the JAX WS implementation. In the JAXWS implementation there is no such method called getHelloPort. So who needs to implement this method? The client class? Also is there any reason not to use the getPort() provided by the JAX ws implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a class generated by the wsimport when creating service proxy (client). Since the class HelloService inherits the Service class which has the getPort function, the getHelloPort is just a customized version of the call. If you look in the generated class HelloService under its function getHelloPort you will see the call getPort is being made.